# Converting Binary Data to PDF in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, binary

I'm working on upgrading a legacy system and have come across a table full of .pdf files saved as binary data.  I have dumped the table into a csv file and am trying to write a script which will take each row and recreate the files that were uploaded in the first place so that I can upload the files to S3.

I have tried this:

```
new_file = open(file_name, "wb")  
doc = doc.encode('utf-8')  
new_file.write(doc)  
new_file.close()
```

where file_name = the saved file name, and doc = the binary data stored as a string in the database.

but all it gives me is a bunk pdf file with the binary data in it.

Here is what the data looks like stored, its just the first bit, way to big to copy and paste.

```
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
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Have you tried to copy the binary content into a new file and make sure it works? Can you post online one example of an original pdf file and also an example of the text that is finally stored on database?

Comment: im pulling the information off of a microsoft sql server.  I can't post a pdf because I cannot create one.  I'll post a snippet

Comment: If you can, post both the file and the bytes on an external site as:
https://mega.co.nz/ and post the link here.

Comment: I don't have the original file, its 2 years old.  And I don't know what the file is, could be confidential for all I know...